# grunt-contrib-handlebars not compiling nested paths

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use `grunt-contrib-handlebars` to compile nested paths and it is not picking the templates in subdirectories `./js/templates/foo/bar.tpl` is being ignored.

```
handlebars: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            namespace: false
        },
        files: {
            "<%= tplOutFileMain %>" : ["js/templates/**/*.tpl"]
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Have you re-verified, all the .tpl files will be compiled into a single file <%= tplOutFileMain %>.

Comment: yeah. its missing all templates inside a subfolder of `./js/templates/<dir>`. I may be using an outdated version of handlebars.